# Discord.py, bot.event works but not bot.command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So if I have implemented bot.event, bot.command doesn't work but if I comment or remove bot.event, bot.command works fine.

In here, bot.command doesn't work but bot.event does:

```
# bot.py
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='dedmu ')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == 'testt':
        await message.channel.send('it works')


@bot.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

If i comment both functions with bot.event, bot.command works perfectly.
What's wrong with it? :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an `on_message` event. When you have `on_message` event in your bot, you need to add `await bot.process_commands(message)` at the last line of your `on_message` event code. Otherwise it will block commands from working.

Comment: it works now! Thank you. Can you explain why does it work that way? 
What does ```await bot.process_commands(message)``` do?

Comment: You should check the [API references](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands). I don't know much more from there.